# Remove attributes to sub folders and files

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, file-attributes

i hide my folders and files through hidden attributes of command prompt,i am struggling to unhidden all sub folders and files,

how i hide the files

in command prompt

> attrib +s +h "foldername"

how i tried to unhide

> attrib -s -h "foldername"

Problem i face :

while i tried to unhide the folder only the folder gets revealed,whereas still the subfolders and files inside the folder remain hidden

how to unhide all subfiles and folders through command prompt else how to remove hidden attributes for subfiles and folders

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add more `/s /d` options to your command

- option `/s` says that "*processes matching files in current folder and all subfolders*"
- option `/d` says that "*processes folders as well*"

> **attrib +s +h /s /d "foldername\*"**
>
> **attrib -s -h /s /d "foldername\*"**

I already tested, it worked for me

Comment: use only `/s` option does not worked, use both `/s` and `/d` options

Answer (score 2):

have you tried the recursive mode

```
attrib -H -S /S
```

found [here](http://nerdfortress.com/2009/12/18/recursively-remove-the-hidden-attribute-on-windows-files/)

Answer (score 1):

Use

> attrib +s +h /s /d "folderpath\*.* "

or

> Use attrib -s -h /s /d "folderpath\*.* "